# mysql server restarts every 30 seconds

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-10.10

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 and mysql server keeps restarting, every 30 seconds or so. If I tail /var/log/syslog I get the following:

```
Jul 26 11:41:57 ubuntu init: mysql post-start process (7981) terminated with status 1 
Jul 26 11:41:57 ubuntu kernel: [ 3088.091492] type=1505 audit(1311676917.680:96):  operation="profile_replace" pid=8055 name="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
Jul 26 11:41:59 ubuntu init: mysql main process (8059) terminated with status 7
Jul 26 11:41:59 ubuntu init: mysql main process ended, respawning
Jul 26 11:42:27 ubuntu init: mysql post-start process (8060) terminated with status 1
Jul 26 11:42:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 3118.264831] type=1505 audit(1311676947.850:97):  operation="profile_replace" pid=8133 name="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
Jul 26 11:42:29 ubuntu init: mysql main process (8137) terminated with status 7
Jul 26 11:42:29 ubuntu init: mysql main process ended, respawning
Jul 26 11:42:57 ubuntu init: mysql post-start process (8138) terminated with status 1
Jul 26 11:42:58 ubuntu kernel: [ 3148.443293] type=1505 audit(1311676978.030:98):  operation="profile_replace" pid=8211 name="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
Jul 26 11:42:59 ubuntu init: mysql main process (8215) terminated with status 7
Jul 26 11:42:59 ubuntu init: mysql main process ended, respawning
```

I cannot start it manually, it just hangs if I try and do so.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check your mysql.error log (usually in /var/log/mysql/)

Comment: @Darhazer thanks for your comment, I checked the logs and found that the my.cnf file had protocol=tcp in that was invalidating the file. Thanks again!

Comment: You might want to update the original post or mark the comment as an answer to get this to stop showing up on the "unanswered" list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Darhazer thanks for your comment, I checked the logs and found that the my.cnf file had protocol=tcp in that was invalidating the file. Thanks again!