# MySQL on ubuntu respawning every 30s

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-10.10

Since I don't know if it's apropriate to ask a question in another one, I opened a new     one- I probably have the same problem as here: [mysql server restarts every 30 seconds](https://serverfault.com/questions/294163/mysql-server-restarts-every-30-seconds)

BUT: My MaSQL is not logging an config error (in fact, I thinke something IS broken in the configuration, because he's not logging at all. But he starts up (and I can connect/use it) but the server gets really slow, and after some time, he's not responding anymore and has to be hard reset.

Can someone please help me checking the config-file? I'll put it below- Good tho know: It's a multi-instance setup. At least instance 2 has that problem

It's an Ubuntu 10.10, MySQL 5.1. My Syslog looks like this:

```
Jan 16 10:03:06 testing2 init: mysql main process (22245) terminated with status 1
Jan 16 10:03:06 testing2 init: mysql main process ended, respawning
Jan 16 10:03:37 testing2 init: mysql post-start process (22246) terminated with status 1
Jan 16 10:03:37 testing2 init: mysql main process (22314) terminated with status 1
Jan 16 10:03:37 testing2 init: mysql main process ended, respawning
Jan 16 10:04:07 testing2 init: mysql post-start process (22315) terminated with status 1
Jan 16 10:04:08 testing2 init: mysql main process (22383) terminated with status 1
Jan 16 10:04:08 testing2 init: mysql main process ended, respawning
Jan 16 10:04:38 testing2 init: mysql post-start process (22384) terminated with status 1
Jan 16 10:04:39 testing2 init: mysql main process (22452) terminated with status 1
Jan 16 10:04:39 testing2 init: mysql main process ended, respawning
Jan 16 10:05:01 testing2 CRON[22519]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null &&     debian-sa1 1 1)
Jan 16 10:05:09 testing2 init: mysql post-start process (22453) terminated with status 1
Jan 16 10:05:09 testing2 init: mysql main process (22540) terminated with status 1
Jan 16 10:05:09 testing2 init: mysql main process ended, respawning
```

Conf:

```
[mysqld_multi]
mysqld     = /usr/sbin/mysqld
mysqladmin = /usr/bin/mysqladmin
user     = debian-sys-maint
password = iYOO9xwrplvgTG5D

[mysqld1]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /export/dat/mysql/mysqld1/mysqld.pid
socket          = /export/dat/mysql/mysqld1/mysqld.sock
port            = 3307
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /export/dat/mysql/mysqld1/data
#tmpdir         = /tmp/mysqld1
tmpdir          = /export1/mysqltmp/mysqld1
language        = /usr/share/mysql/english
log             = /var/log/mysql/mysql1.log
log-error       = /var/log/mysql/mysql1.error
skip-external-locking
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 64M
thread_stack        = 128K
thread_cache_size   = 8
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 256M
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
character_set_server    =utf8
default-character-set   =utf8
innodb_buffer_pool_size =700M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=10M
innodb_log_file_size    =100M
innodb_log_buffer_size  =4M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
innodb_data_home_dir    =/export/dat/mysql/mysqld1/innodbfiles
innodb_file_per_table
lower_case_table_names=1 
table_cache=512
tmp_table_size=18M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
innodb_thread_concurrency=8

# Log slow queries, time threshold set by 'long_query_time',
#log_slow_queries = /var/log/mysql_query.log
#log_output                        = FILE                    # 5.1 only
#long_query_time = 5

ignore_builtin_innodb
plugin-load=innodb=ha_innodb_plugin.so;innodb_trx=ha_innodb_plugin.so;innodb_locks=ha_innodb_plugin.so;innodb_lock_waits=ha_innodb_plugin.so;innodb_cmp=ha_innodb_plugin.so;innodb_cmp_reset=ha_innodb_plugin.so;innodb_cmpmem=ha_innodb_plugin.so;innodb_cmpmem_reset=ha_innodb_plugin.so

default-storage-engine=InnoDB
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_file_format=barracuda
innodb_strict_mode=1


[mysqld2]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /export/dat/mysql/mysqld2/mysqld.pid
socket          = /export/dat/mysql/mysqld2/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /export/dat/mysql/mysqld2/data
#tmpdir         = /tmp/mysqld2

tmpdir          = /export1/mysqltmp/mysqld2
language        = /usr/share/mysql/english
log             = /var/log/mysql/mysql2.log
log-error       = /var/log/mysql/mysql2.error
skip-external-locking
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 64M
thread_stack        = 128K
thread_cache_size   = 8
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 256M
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
character_set_server    =utf8
default-character-set   =utf8
innodb_buffer_pool_size =700M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=10M
innodb_log_file_size    =100M
innodb_log_buffer_size  =4M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
loose_innodb_data_home_dir      =/export/dat/mysql/mysqld2/innodbfiles
#innodb_file_per_table
lower_case_table_names=1 
table_cache=512
tmp_table_size=18M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
innodb_thread_concurrency=8

# Log slow queries, time threshold set by 'long_query_time',
#log_slow_queries = /var/log/mysql_query.log
#log_output                        = FILE                    # 5.1 only
#long_query_time = 3

ignore_builtin_innodb
plugin-load=innodb=ha_innodb_plugin.so;innodb_trx=ha_innodb_plugin.so;innodb_locks=ha_innodb_plugin.so;innodb_lock_waits=ha_innodb_plugin.so;innodb_cmp=ha_innodb_plugin.so;innodb_cmp_reset=ha_innodb_plugin.so;innodb_cmpmem=ha_innodb_plugin.so;innodb_cmpmem_reset=ha_innodb_plugin.so

default-storage-engine=InnoDB
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_file_format=barracuda
innodb_strict_mode=1
```

Thanks

Comment: What's in the mysqld logs?

Comment: try to stop the mysqld service (usually executing "service mysql stop"), then start it without resource control (using the mysqld command, on a shell), look for output from the command, and if it exits take a look to the log and log-error locations of your config file. *something* should be outputted.

Comment: I already restartet it multiple times. Since the init script isn't multi, i use /usr/bin/mysqld_multi start 2 --log /var/log/mysql/startup2.log for instance 2. Logging: I forgot to create the log-file. I'll created it now and will restart mysql as soon as possible (co worker is currently exporting databases). This is the startup-log: http://pastebin.com/PLQfD2Wi I'll also fix thos two deprectated, but they're probably not the cause

Comment: mysql is still not logging at all.

Comment: you fixed the log location (or file) and now you no longer have errors during mysqld starting (the ones in your pastebin no longer shows) and still mysqld is crashing within 30seconds without any error in mysql2.log, mysql2.err or syslog?

Comment: unfortunately yes: http://pastebin.com/0gvZ0bez

Comment: I don't know how to help then. nevertheless it seems you are running mysqld with a resource controller again, otherwise init shouldn't start the service automatically when it crashes. I wonder if, when it restarts, the logs are cleaned (although it's not the behaviour I’d expect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I found the cause...

It was the init-script of the package. Since I changed the default setup to a multi-setup, I used my own scripts to stop and start those two instances. But it looks like an package update has activated the default init-script which is not working with my setup. so I deactivated it again:

```
service mysql stop
update-rc.d -f mysql remove
```

Since then, the syslog is not longer filled up with respawning-messages. Now I go ahead, searching the cause for not logging anything ;-)

anyway, thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 1):

On my system -- (10.10 running mysqld_multi), I had a mysql.conf script under /etc/init/ that I had to remove to resolve the errors. Not really sure how/why it ended up there, but it was doing the exact same respawn